# gvfs metadata through ssh

Tags: ssh, nautilus, gvfs

I have a problem with the gvfs daemon

I have a mounted gvfsd-fuse

```
$ mount | grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

on pc1 (not using ssh)

```
$ gvfs-info -w $HOME
<...>
Writable attribute namespaces:
metadata (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
xattr (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
xattr-sys (string, Keep with file when moved)
```

but when I log with ssh on this machine

```
$ ssh -X user@pc1
$ gvfs-info -w $HOME
<...>
Writable attribute namespaces:
xattr (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
xattr-sys (string, Keep with file when moved)
```

The **metadata** part is missing, which is needed when I use nautilus over ssh and I change the per folder settings (i.e. zoom or file sorting).

```
$ ssh -X user@pc1
$ nautilus
=> changing the zoom level for example, then change folder, go back, the zoom setting is lost (reset to default)
this does not happen when I log physically on this machine.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found an answer after a few hours.

It seems that the dbus daemon is not launched for the remote ssh session.

So using the existing DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS was failing, but I found a solution [HERE](https://serverfault.com/a/411326/377094):

```
$ ssh -X user@pc1 "gnome-terminal -e 'dbus-launch --exit-with-session bash'"
$ nautilus
```

I starts up a new session bus or find the existing bus address on the X display, so that the aplication can communicate with the gvfs daemon.